# Rviz Amcl spreading over time when stayin still

Tags: ros, navigation, gazebo, amcl, ros-noetic

I am trying Multirobot navigation with the navigation_stack and the Rviz, in ros noetic. When i publish the amcl when starting, the spread looks normal. Then i publish a goal, the robot moves and the amcl works perfect finding exaclty where the robot is. After some time that the robot doesnt move the amcl starts to spread again. I am providing some screenshots. Does this happen to anyone too ? [image: the black arrows are the acml that spread through time, After achiving the goal it was looking like the other robot(red arrows)]
I have to add that the spread looks random sometimes, but i can also have this line looking sape.
[image]
the amcl for the first robots looks like this:

```
<param name="use_map_topic"             value="$(arg use_map_topic)"/>
<param name="global_frame_id"           value="$(arg global_frame_id)"/>
<param name="min_particles"             value="500"/>
<param name="max_particles"             value="3000"/>
<param name="kld_err"                   value="0.02"/>
<param name="update_min_d"              value="0.20"/>
<param name="update_min_a"              value="0.20"/>
<param name="resample_interval"         value="1"/>
<param name="transform_tolerance"       value="0.5"/>
<param name="recovery_alpha_slow"       value="0.00"/>
<param name="recovery_alpha_fast"       value="0.00"/>
<param name="initial_pose_x"            value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
<param name="initial_pose_y"            value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
<param name="initial_pose_a"            value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
<param name="gui_publish_rate"          value="50.0"/>


<param name="laser_max_range"           value="3.5"/>
<param name="laser_max_beams"           value="180"/>
<param name="laser_z_hit"               value="0.5"/>
<param name="laser_z_short"             value="0.05"/>
<param name="laser_z_max"               value="0.05"/>
<param name="laser_z_rand"              value="0.5"/>
<param name="laser_sigma_hit"           value="0.2"/>
<param name="laser_lambda_short"        value="0.1"/>
<param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
<param name="laser_model_type"          value="likelihood_field"/>

<param name="odom_model_type"           value="diff"/>
<param name="odom_alpha1"               value="0.1"/>
<param name="odom_alpha2"               value="0.1"/>
<param name="odom_alpha3"               value="0.1"/>
<param name="odom_alpha4"               value="0.1"/>
<param name="odom_frame_id"             value="tb3_0_tf/odom"/>
<param name="base_frame_id"             value="tb3_0_tf/base_footprint"/>
<remap from="scan"                      to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
<remap from="initialpose"               to="/tb3_0/initialpose"/>
<remap from="amcl_pose"                 to="/tb3_0/amcl_pose"/>
<remap from="particlecloud"             to="/tb3_0/particlecloud"/>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the AMCL parameters you are using (in text form, not a screen shot.) Also tell us which ros release you are using.

Comment: I have seen similar behavior, not exactly the same. In my case I found it was caused by an occassional corrupted odom packet coming from the HW. I added a filter to scan for bad packets and it went away.  Is your issue in simulation or on real  robots?

Comment: @Mike973 I did upload it, I am using ros noetic, you can check it thanks

Comment: @billy can explain me how to ckeck if there is any bad package and how to filter them ? thanks a lot.  I am only working in simulation for now, gazebo

Comment: I would not expect to see this particle spreading from the amcl parameters you provide. Does it also happen if you simulate only a single robot?

Comment: @Mike973 no, do u think this has to do, the odometry not being initialized to the robot's spawn state , but at 0,0 ? [**photo link**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HPJeyrjf7PadJsVNs1kRLONqs28lCbF6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you're in simulation you don't need to worry about bad odom packets.

Comment: There is some conflict within your multi-robot configuration. Can you share your catkin_ws/src/ files ?

Comment: thesse are the main source files, I launch the main4_robots and then the navigation4_robots [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rtobE2PwfSEKE4ESGT7I2WngxcNCtVnI?usp=drive_link)

Comment: @Michalis Google is not allowing me to view your files. You need to allow public read access.

Comment: you are right, check this [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rtobE2PwfSEKE4ESGT7I2WngxcNCtVnI?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could it be a problem that I publish the goal for the move_base once only, and not repeatedly ?

Comment: No, that is not a factor. move_base only requires that the goal be given once.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that your launch files rely on the obsolete `tf_prefix` feature. This feature was deprecated long ago, and I believe it is not reliably supported in noetic (meaning some ros nodes still support it, but most do not.)

Without this string prefix in the frame_id values, your robots will have duplicate TF frame names. This is a problem, and will break your simulation in odd ways.

You can determine if this is the issue by echoing topics `/tf` and `/tf_static`. Except for frame_id "map" (which is shared), what you want to see is that all the frame_id and child_frame_id values start with `tb3_#_tf`.

Comment: I think there is no problem with that, I uploaded in the google drive link above screenshot echoing the tf, tf_static and the tf_tree

Comment: how can I create the namespaces if I dont use tf_prefix ?

Comment: Yes, I agree that the tf_tree.png file on google drive shows all the frame_id have the expected prefixes. I don't have any other suggestions right now.

Comment: I just found out, that the same phenomenon happens with one robot, no namespaces and tf_prefix added, I uploaded a photo in google drive

Comment: I found the main problem. The turtlebot seems to turn clockwise by itself, so the amcl gets confused by /scan topic . I dodnt know why this happens, I am monitoring the cmd_vel topic but zero velocities are published. Only the move base node subscribes to this topic. Should i upload a new question?  [photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16X5W_6g7ey0Khq27a3d1OJR-Ph20s3vc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MPEfpV75lcOuCYQIlj6aaAcncWMBaeyk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: "turn by itself" - yes, I think you should make it a new question.